# Is a damage die replaced by the DoS if they are higher than that roll?

Tags: combat, rogue-trader

I'm using Wolph42's framework for RT, and on the settings there's an option to turn that rule on or off. In that option's description it states that it's rules as written for all FFG40k systems except for Dark Heresy.

It states that, when a character performs a test to make an attack, if the lowest damage die roll is smaller than the number of Degrees of Success, then the DoS value is applied instead.

For example, if Titus has a BS of 60 and rolls a 10, which means he has 5 DoS, but then his damage rolls (2d10) result in a 7 and a 1, his lowest die (1) will be replaced by the DoS (5), for a total damage of 7+5=12.

I've been looking for that rule in the RT core rulebook to no avail, and I can't recall hearing or reading about it before. Is this rule correct?

PS: I assume that if it's a single die weapon, the result would also be replaced by the DoS if they're higher than the damage roll.

Comment: I have never heard of this rule in Death Watch either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Deathwatch such a rule does indeed exist. 
On page 245 if the Core Rule Book 'Step Four: Attacker Determines Damage' 
It says: 'For all attack rolls, count the Degrees of Success. The number of Degrees of Success is the minimum amount of Damage that attack will inflict on a single dice. If the attack influcts more than one dice of Damage, the player may apply the Degrees of Success from the attack roll as the minimum result to one dice of his choice. '
So I could imagine a similar rule to be in affect for RT.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, unfortunately.

Comment: I am sorry, as someone else quoted Deathwatch, I thought it was ok and at least would provide an idea where to look in the RT rule book.

Comment: It is indeed a helpful comment, since the Framework was designed for Deathwatch, Only War, and Dark Heresy as well.

EDIT: Found the rule, it's in the Rogue Trader core rulebook, page 245: "The attacker
may choose to replace the result on a single damage dice with
the number of degrees of success from his attack roll. If the
attack inflicts more than one dice of damage, the attacker may
replace the result on one dice of his choice with the degrees
of success from the attack roll."
So, yes, this rule is indeed correct.